# Connect to instance in SSMS

Tags: sql-server, ssms, firewall, sql-server-2016

here is the **problem** Im facing:

[image: problem]

This happens when I try to **access an instance in SSMS**.

It started by installing **SQL Server 2016 Enterprise With Service Pack 1 64-bit**.

Than, installed SSMS to create a database in it, as normal.

*Didn't reach this point yet because simply can't connect to the instance.*

Been through a really long process to make sure everything was ok:

1. See if MS SQL Server is started.
2. See if Firewall is allowing port 1433.
3. See if TCP/IP protocol is enabled for MS SQL protocols.
4. Make sure the database engine is configured to accept remote connections.
5. make sure you are using an instance name in your connection strings. ( Usually the format needed to specify the database server is machinename\instancename )
6. Make sure the login account has access permission on the database you used during login.

Can't seem to find the problem, any help here?

Comment: Windows auth? Then try connecting to (local) as database server.

Comment: yes, windows auth.
What do you mean with (local)?

Comment: Open SSMS, and, on `Server Name`, write down (local) and press connect

Comment: @Hackerman Ive tried and added just the computer name on it, but get promped with error 40 and error 2...

Comment: ok, that worked... thank you. why is that?

Comment: It's because when you do a default installation of sql server, to connect to that instance you just need to specify . (dot) OR (local) as the server name

Comment: ok, thank you for your help!

Comment: I am glad to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the way I've solved it was:

Open SSMS, and, on Server Name, write down (local) , and press connect .
This happens because when you do a default installation of SQL Server, to connect to that instance you just need to specify . (dot) OR (local) as the server name.

all credits go to [Hackerman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1987838/hackerman).